# Flash: change x,y=0,0 to top right corner, instead of top left

Tags: flash, coordinates, right-to-left

Is there a way in Flash to change the x,y axis-system so that 0,0 will be the top-right corner of the stage instead of the top left? (for when I'm developing something in an RTL language - the positioning calculations will be easier to handle...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't that I'm aware of (It may exist in a localized version of Flash Designer). But you could always just pump coordinates through a utility function that would discover the width of the DisplayObject, and convert that way. Something like this:

```
function convertRTL(x:int, o:DisplayObject):int {
    return o.width - x;
}
```